# In MySQL, is a BIT column a suitable way to store 5, 6, or 7-byte integers?

Tags: mysql, bit-fields, types

I have a table whose size I'd like to keep down, and one of the columns can be treated as a 5-byte unsigned integer. This is a column that I **won't** need to search by.

MySQL offers integer datatypes

- `TINYINT`, for 1-byte integers
- `SMALLINT`, for 2-byte integers
- `MEDIUMINT`, for 3-byte integers
- `INT`, for 4-byte integers
- `BIGINT`, for 8-byte integers.

But it also offers `BIT(M)`, for 1 ≤ M ≤ 64. This stores (effectively) an unsigned integer from 0 to 2<sup>M-1</sup>. Is there a reason to avoid using a `BIT(40)` column to store a 5-byte integer? (As I said, I will not need to search by this column. Any difficulties relating to query execution speed may therefore be ignored.)

Comment: Data in your RDMBs that you don't need to search today has an annoying habit of becoming data you want to search tomorrow. Furthermore, disk is cheap and micro-optimizations are expensive. See Sjored's answer.

Comment: This sounds a lot like premature optimization. Do you really have that much data that you need to save every single byte and is there nothing else that saves you more space left? Using something other than INT's to store integers is not maintainable, will cause problems when the data grows (i.e. what if you suddenly _need_ 41 bits? Do you use BIT(41) then?) and is very, very ugly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL treats BIT as textual data and not numbers. Usually this is the reason working with BIT should be avoided - it may be a little bit confusing. For example, we want to store number 57 in BIT(8) column. The number 57 will be stored as `b'00111001' i.e. binary representative of 57. But it will be displayed as 9 as 57 is ASCII code of '9'. To get proper integer value you have convert columns data to numerical value. You can test this behaviour with:

```
CREATE TABLE testbit(a BIT(8));
INSERT INTO testbit VALUES (b'00111001');
INSERT INTO testbit VALUES (57);
SELECT a FROM testbit;
SELECT a+0 FROM testbit;
```

Comment: OK, this convinces me. I'll make it a `BIGINT` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Use the native integer types, such as tinyint.

Using a bit field does not save any bytes. That is, a bit field of 1 to 8 bits takes 1 byte and will thus occupy as much space as a tinyint.

Also, bitfields are a bit harder to work with if you only want to use them as numbers.

Edit: Actually, in some cases it may save some bytes. However, I would still advice using the integer types.